# Can some basement walls be framed on subfloor and others not?

Tags: basement, framing, subfloor

I have a basement that has some framing already done - mostly interior walls, some of which I believe are load bearing.

I want to put down some subfloor, and the subflooring recommendations I've read all prefer framing on top of the subfloor. These sources say subflooring between walls is possible but not preferred.

My question: can I subfloor in between the existing walls and put the new walls on the subfloor? I.e., have a mixture of walls on the subfloor and on the concrete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are proposing is ok for partition walls.

Subfloors, as the name implies are the base that is under a finished floor.
The question is why do you need to build a subfloor over your basement floor?
If it is that the concrete is not level, that can be addressed other ways, such as leveling compound.

EDIT SINCE NEW INFO:

It sounds like you want to build a platform over the basement floor, so it can be insulated for comfort. That would be ok. Any load bearing walls that are currently there should stay and build your platform around them. Partition walls can be built on the platform. (along the block walls is ok too.) My concerned would be dampness. You need to be sure the basement stays dry under the platform. –

Comment: Would it also be ok for the "outside" walls that would be along the cinderblock? I am wanting a subfloor primarily for comfort (the concrete gets cold in Michigan winters).

Comment: @StephenCleary any wall that you add at this point will be nonstructural, so have at it.  Your only concern will be supporting the wall(s) horizontally, i.e. so they don't fall down on their own.